# find empty files in parallel

Tags: find

find always lists files in lexicographic order because that's how it performs depth-first searches. If we're willing to relax that restriction, is it possible to improve the parallelism of find or to use another, similar tool to look for empty files? (I'm also curious about strategies for looking for files using other `find`-like criteria, but for the sake of concreteness let's use empty files).

So, I'm trying to find all the empty files in my home directory in any order.

On OS X using bash, I run the following command

```
$ find . -type f -empty >& /dev/null
real    0m10.334s
user    0m0.525s
sys 0m5.568s
```

In an attempt to improve the parallelism, I did the simplest thing I could possibly think of and used invoked find once per directory using a Perl script. The Perl script just ones run `find` per top-level directory or file in its own process.

The total elapsed time for the script is a little under half that of the single find.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

opendir(my $fh, '.');

while (readdir($fh)) {
    my $item = $_;
    next if $item eq '.';
    next if $item eq '..';

    my $cpid = fork();
    if ($cpid == -1) {
        die;
    } elsif ($cpid == 0) {
        exec 'find', "./$item", '-type', 'f', '-empty', or die;
    }
}

while (wait() != -1) {}
```

For example

```
$ time perl find-parallel.pl >& /dev/null
real    0m4.245s
user    0m1.126s
sys 0m8.281s
```

Using a script of some kind to manually run independent `find`s at a certain depth seems like a rather clumsy approach to this problem. Is there a better way?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  If you're trying to speed things up, this is like counting sheep by counting the legs and dividing by 4: parallel find is going to be slower, and a _lot_ harder to get right.

Comment: Use gnu parallel in https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minor nit first: The order of output for find is not lexographic, at least on Linux. Instead it's in the directory index order (which is frequently creation order).

`exec` itself, down to the syscall `execve`, has a non-trivial overhead at the scale you're working, so you'd need to avoid it.

As a general framework for the solution, you need at least a base of two threads:

- queue manager
- worker(s)

Logic:

1. The queue starts with a single directory `.`.
2. Whenever there is something available in the queue, and we have not reached the limit of parallel threads, start a worker with one item from the queue.
3. The worker: reads the given directory, non-recursively.
4. For new directory it sees, append directory to queue.
5. For other new file, handle normally.

Special cases that need handling:

- Multiple symlinks to the same thing.
- Symlinks to other directories (depending on your design needs you might to not follow, or have to follow multiple times).
- Circular loops if following symlinks to higher-levels.

Will this perform better than a non-parallel find? That's a difficult question, and also comes down to the filesystem/kernel in use.

If you're looking for pre-built solutions, as an example, look for Go parallel directory walkers, but beware the cost of [extra `stat` calls](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16399).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a free parallel find tool for Linux on Github, which I wrote in C++:
https://github.com/breuner/elfindo

You would use it like this to find empty files:

```
$ elfindo . -type f -size 0
```

You can set the number of threads explicity via the `-threads` parameter:

```
$ elfindo . -type f -size 0 -threads 32
```